# Syntax error near unexpected token 'which'

Tags: bash, osx, which

I'm trying to script something in OS X Automator and i ultimately want to send the output of `which npm` to `<npm> install` and i'm getting the error `Syntax error near unexpected token 'which'`

Any idea why and how to resolve?

[image]

Comment: you used the correct `$( which ...) ` once, but not twice ...?

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo.  You're missing a `$` before the `(which npm)`

So you want `$(which npm)`

The structure `$(...)` means "run the command inside the brackets and return the output"

Comment: `$(cmd)` means run the `cmd` and replace the whole $(cmd) with the standard out of the cmd.

Answer (score 1):

Missing the $ on the first line, mate.

Comment: While true, this answer could be a bit more direct about where the missing `$` goes...